# Default behaviour right arrow to enter key Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, keystroke

I'm coding an application in swing and in a Jtable I need that the default behaviour goes from right arrow to enter key, moving to the right cell on press enter.

I've seen how override the default behaviour of enter with this method:

```
private void createKeybindings(JTable table) {
    table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "Enter");
        table.getActionMap().put("Enter", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            }
        });
    }
```

But I don't know how to transport the behaviour of the right arrow to enter key, in the actionPerfomed, for moving right a press enter. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't override the default behaviour of the Enter key.

Just share the right arrow action with the Enter key:

The basic code to share an Action with a different KeyStroke:

```
KeyStroke existingKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT");
KeyStroke addedKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");
InputMap im = component.getInputMap(...);
im.put(addedKeyStroke, im.get(existingKeyStroke));
```